# How do I specify the return type for fn functions in Mojo

Tags: mojolang

I am running a piece of code that calculates the factorial in Mojo:

```
fn fact(x:Int):
    var mul:Int=1
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        mul = mul*i
    return mul
print(fact(7))
```

But when I run this, I get the error: `cannot implicitly convert 'Int' value to 'None' in return value`

```
return mul
```

I tried using `fn:Int`, but that's not the correct syntax

Answer (score 6):

In Mojo, the return type of a function is specified after the colon (:) following the function's parameter list. To specify the return type for the fact function in your code, you can use the -> operator followed by the desired return type.

Check this :

```
fn fact(x: Int) -> Int:
    var mul: Int = 1
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        mul = mul * i
    return mul

print(fact(7))
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but your description is wrong. It's after the goes to operator `->`, not colon.

Answer (score 0):

In Mojo, the return type of a function is specified after the `->` symbol, not after the function name. The correct syntax to specify a return type for your `fact` function would be to place `-> Int` after the parameter list, like so:

```cpp
fn fact(x: Int) -> Int:
    var mul: Int = 1
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        mul = mul * i
    return mul

print(fact(7))
```

With this syntax, you're correctly specifying that the `fact` function should return an `Int`, which will resolve the error you were seeing.